# How to launch several terminals with an application?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

I'd like to have a terminal that opens `htop` every time it is launched, along with two other terminal tabs (if possible), for me to run other commands.

Is there any terminal app in existence that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply can do it (when you use gnome-terminal) with:

```
gnome-terminal -- htop
```

you could make yourself a `.desktop` file for that with the following content and place it in `~/.local/share/applications`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Htop
Comment=my cool htop terminal
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -- /usr/bin/htop
Terminal=True
Type=Application
```

If you for example want this terminal to be maximized you can use the following `Exec` line:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --maximize -- /usr/bin/htop
```

To have it open multiple tabs with different commands you can concatenate gnome-terminal commands on the `Exec` line with `&&` and use the `--tab option` example below for one `htop` terminal and a second terminal using `top`:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -- /usr/bin/htop && /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -- /usr/bin/top
```

You could even assign the above lines without the `Exec=` to a shortcut via the shortcut manager (keyboard settings).

Comment: Can it also open multiple tabs on start up?

Comment: Yes. New Exec line in @Videonauth's answer: `Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -- /usr/bin/htop & /usr/bin/gnome-terminal & /usr/bin/gnome-terminal`

Comment: @RolandiXor im pretty sure it can, gnome-terminal has a ton of run options, you simply would need to concatenate the different commands with `&&` as muclux pointed out.

Comment: @muclux & will simply drop the programm to background, you want `&&` for that.

Comment: I can't edit my comment any more but I'm sure you will be able my comment with @Videonauth's. However you will not have one terminal with 3 tabs, but 3 terminals.

Comment: @RolandiXor I'm actually trying to figure out how to open them all in tabs in one window, as far I can read from the help, it should be possible. If you have questions according to this answers ping me in chat.